# Author Tracking code, for wordpress!

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I need help with coding this piece. Basically i want with someone click on my author page. It stored a cookie of that author name and email. I want the cookie to stay in place untill the person close their browser, or however long. not a big deal. I should then be able to use this info in any gravityform on my site. Basically i am tracking leads generated by my authors. If you have a better way of doing this, i am happy for suggestions. Thanks . Heres is my current author.php code to get the author info

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
else :
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) {
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
setcookie("author_name", $curauth);
}
?>
```

for reading data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['author_name'])){
  echo $_COOKIE['author_name'];
}
?>
```